# JOOQ with SQL DataWarehouse?

Tags: jooq, sql-data-warehouse

Does ***JOOQ*** support dialect for "***SQL DataWarehouse***"?
Any pointers .

Answer (score 0):

From a jOOQ perspective, SQL Data Warehouse is just another flavour of SQL Server as can be seen in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-reference-tsql-statements

Like SQL Server, SQL Data Warehouse implements parts of the T-SQL language

Answer (score 0):

I question why you're planning to use a Java-focussed query generator with an MPP data warehouse. If you're intending to use it for updates, deletes, etc. in some kind of ETL flow, you're going to be in a world of pain.

Nothing wrong with JOOQ, but maybe not the right technology for interacting with ASDW.